# Copy commands seem to wait for eachother or lock eachothers process - why?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, ssd, nas

I have a recent computer (i9-10900K, 32GB RAM) in which there are three disks. One SSD (512GB), and two HDDs (each 4TB).

Whenever I perform a copy from one disk to another, or from one disk to any of my NAS devices, files are copied very fast and all appears to be fine.

However, when I start two separate copy commands (say for instance from SSD to NAS, and HDD1 to HDD2), it all starts out fast, slows down, and then appears to hang (for minutes) until all processes start picking up speed again. This repeats several times throughout the copy process. It doesn't matter if source or target are the same drive, or other drives, or network locations.

I've noticed that copying several small files appears to "wait" until a large file being copied is done - as soon as it's done, the "deadlock" appears to be gone.

The manner in which I perform the copy does not change anything: copy/xcopy/robocopy via command prompt, copying in Explorer, copying in Total Commander, or any other utility: the behaviour is always the same.

What could cause this? Or how can I investigate this to find out what's going on? It's very annoying to say the least...

Thanks!

Comment: One aspect to consider and maybe looking at your motherboard documentation is 1. Do all these drives use the same storage controller? 2. Are all of the drives using the same bus on the motherboard? If either of these are capping - they have to wait for i/o to drop before it can initiate the subsequent copy. In consumer motherboards, throughput is not really a priority to manufacturers.

Comment: Do you get the same problem when copying files in one job, but using multiple threads via `/MT`? for example: `robocopy.exe source destination *.* /MT:16`, with multiple files in 'source'

Comment: @Narzard: I'm thinking motherboard as well, but capping is not the case I guess. If the speeds drop, they drop to ridiculously low speeds (as in a few kb/s for +1GB sized files). Just now, I've waited for a single file of a few megabytes to be copied, it took nearly 5 minutes, but another copy of 200GB was happening at the same time...

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I could run a test and see what the results are, but I doubt it would make a difference. The issue is not related to robocopy, as I'm using other methods of copying files and it also presents itself when not using robocopy. I'll do the test anyway, and update the question tomorrow.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I ran the test and started copying a few thousand images with /MT:8, but I had to give it up after half a minute or so, because the copy process appeared to be "stuck". Again, the same behaviour as I mentioned in my reply to Narzard: speeds dropping to a few kb/s, for files that are a minimum of 5Mb in size.

Comment: @Deekay can you try specifically SSD-to-SSD and NAS-to-NAS? A network copy should exclude most storage hardware-related stuff. It is worth checking your motherboard manufacturer's website for their current chipset/storage drivers as well, since this sounds more like buggy behavior than a real choke point getting hit

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: SSD-to-SSD copying also affected when other transfers are happening. Copying files from one NAS to the same NAS is always done on the device itself, so isn't impacted obviously, but NAS-to-NAS copies made from one NAS to another, or from one NAS to itself via my PC are also affected. I'm going to follow your advice and check for new drivers for my motherboard, and check if these change the behaviour (hopefully). Thanks!